# Activity feed on admin dashboard

Tags: actions, feed

Is it possible to create an activity feed for a user on the WordPress admin dashboard for the activity on that blog?

e.g.

"Admin published a post - 12:00 Jan 12, 2013"

"User2 updated page 'xyz' - 16:35 Jan 10, 2013"

"New user 'User2' created - 09:06 Jan 9, 2013"

etc.

Are there any plugins that would collect data like this so that I can output it with PHP or is there a native WordPress way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:http://wordpress.org/plugins/aryo-activity-log/
Keeps a log of updates.

Comment: Oh that looks really cool, I'm going to do some research into that :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might.